# Autocomplete field set created value

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm using Sonata 3 in my project. I faced with the problem with autocomplete field.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    $form
        ->add(
            'contactPerson',
            ModelAutocompleteType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Contact Person',
                'property' => 'name',
                'model_manager' => $this->modelManager,
                'class' => ContactPerson::class,
                'btn_add' => 'Add new',
                'callback' => [CustomerCompanyFilters::class, 'filterContactPersons'],
            ]
        )
}
```

I added 'Add new' button and can create a new entity in popup, but it is not set automatically as a field value, I need to search it again. Is it possible to set field value just after pressing 'Create' button popup?

Comment: I think it's possible using ajax

Comment: autocomplete form type uses ajax to create a new entity, but it doesn't set a relation to created item